# Laravel 4 image upload returns null

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4

I have a Laravel form that allows files to be uploaded through an Ajax call:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'upload/image', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'profile-form')) }}
{{ Form::file('avatar', $attributes = array( 'id' => 'file-avatar', 'style' => 'display:none' )) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And a Route:

```
Route::post('upload/image', function(){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(Input::file('avatar'));
    echo "</pre>";
});
```

Actually the `var_dump()` returns `NULL`.
If I replace `Input::file('avatar')` with `$_FILES` in my Route I get the following result in the Chrome developer tool:

Preview tab:

```
undefined: {undefined: 2041196, 4371.jpg: ["type"], image/jpeg: ["tmp_name"],…}
4371.jpg: ["type"]
0: "type"
/var/www/clients/client1/web3/tmp/phpmoigFb: ["error"]
0: "error"
image/jpeg: ["tmp_name"]
0: "tmp_name"
undefined: 2041196
```

Response tab:

```
<pre>array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "4371.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(43) "/var/www/clients/client1/web3/tmp/phpmoigFb"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(2041196)
  }
}
</pre>
```

What am I missing?

I am using:

```
php artisan --version
Laravel Framework version 4.2.16
```

And my php.ini:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 8M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

**EDIT**

A `var_dump()` on `Input::all()` gives in the Chrome developer tool:

Preview tab:

```
undefined: {undefined: 9, 2789.jpg: ["mimeType"], image/jpeg: ["size"],…}
2789.jpg: ["mimeType"]
0: "mimeType"
/var/www/clients/client1/web3/tmp/php9MJkdO: ["fileName", "SplFileInfo"]
0: "fileName"
1: "SplFileInfo"
image/jpeg: ["size"]
0: "size"
undefined: 9
```

Response tab:

```
<pre>array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
    ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(8) "2789.jpg"
    ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    int(1860197)
    ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(43) "/var/www/clients/client1/web3/tmp/php9MJkdO"
    ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(9) "php9MJkdO"
  }
}
</pre>
```

Comment: may i know which os you using?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: so may be your file permission error , your folder need to be set 777 permission

Comment: I just did a chmod 777 on the tmp folder and I still get the same issue/error. I have edit my question with another test results.

Comment: than please try to use simple <input type="file" name="avatar"> instead of laravel file lib, let's see what happen?

Comment: Same result: `<pre>NULL</pre>`

Comment: If I add a submit button and remove the jQuery code, it works properly. It seems to be an issue with the Ajax upload not with the code itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70148/discussion-between-arrakeen-and-ankit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I will answer to my own question and I am sorry if it was not relevant enough since I forgot to provide the Javascript code.

The problem was located at this line:

```
var data = new FormData( $( '#profile-form')[0] );
```

If you have two forms or more on the same page (that's the case for me), you need to get the form element from the jQuery array with  `[0]` (depends on the form position) othewise it won't work properly...

I hope it will help someone else to not waste so much time as I did today.